# regex alphanumeric jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

```
var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]+$/;

if(regx.test($($input).val()))
  alert ("correct");
else
  alert('Incorrect!');
}
```

If I enter in input, character @ or # works? for me this works, but I think that must be incorrect...

Why does not works fine?

Comment: `$val` looks like a jQuery object, according to code conventions. Don't wrap it in another `$` object.

Comment: @Robw: I assume you mean $input? But yes, I agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing an opening brace `{`

Change your `if ... else` statement to:

```
var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]+$/;

if (regx.test('#sdfgsdfg'))
    alert("correct"); // alerts
else
    alert('Incorrect!');​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bp6fg/

Answer (score 0):

regex alphanumeric jquery with length 5-10 
var regx=/^([a-zA-Z0-9 _.-]){3,10}$/

```
    $('#txtSearchIn').keyup(function() {
        if (regx.test(this.value)) 
            $('#lblErrorMsg').val('');
        else 
            $('#lblErrorMsg').val('text should be alphanumeric as well as max length 5-10 charater');
    });
```